# Bridge interface with VLAN tagging

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, bridge, proxmox

I need my Proxmox instance to accept traffic from another VLAN and I'm having trouble with setting the interface correctly. I have 1 NIC, I've configured a port on my switch as a trunk interface, now I only need the correct configuration in /etc/network/interfaces file.

My current config looks like this:

```
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        bridge_ports eno1
        bridge_vlan_aware yes
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

iface enp8s0 inet manual
```

Unfortunately, it's not working. When this configuration is applied, the machine is no longer reachable over the network. How can I make it accept tagged traffic?

I've also tried this command `bridge vlan add vid 2-4094 dev eno1`, however that did not do the trick as well.

Also, is it possible to get this to work without declaring another IP in the subnet that is tied to this other VLAN I am trying to access?

Comment: Can you post/state the configuration of the entire switch?  It is not normally the Proxmox instance's job to assign incoming traffic to a VLAN.  You can configure the port on the switch (or the proxmox) for a native vlan, but that will assign all untagged traffic.  If you want to have everything on the same VLAN then it would be much easier for you to make the changes on the switch and turn the VLAN capabilities off for the Proxmox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a vlan interface. Only through this way, machines will be able to reach it and viceversa.

There's only one option, that a router exists between those two machines.

I must say that I usually don't define a network for default vlans but only different subnets for different vlan networks